# Integration REST API to send custom email in signup process

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to integrate REST API to send custom email during signup process, in the custom policies, In the email I will send an OTP and then will verify it,

I was able to integrate REST API but not able to call the API during signup process only.
The api is getting called even during signIn process.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

So in step (6), Select a user flow type, you want to select the "Sign up" option only.

6.On the Create a user flow page, select the Sign up and sign in user flow.

See whether this helps or perhaps leads toward a path to the solution.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: I am working with custom policies not user flows.